# Upgrade php 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, installation

I'm having bit of a trouble here. I have a SLES machine which was running on php 5.3, but for some reason it was downgraded to 5.2. Since 5.3 can't be installed over YAST (repositories aren't up to date, and there's no connection to the internet to update those) I have to install php from source.

I have googled and read the INSTALL documentation, but I can't figure out how to install 5.3 the same way it was before. The current installation is in /etc/php5 with apache being installed in /etc/apache2, and I need support for PDO with PostGres. phpinfo states the following for the configure command

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr' '--datadir=/usr/share/php5'
'--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--with-libdir=lib64'
'--includedir=/usr/include' '--sysconfdir=/etc/php5/apache2'
'--with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2'
'--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d'
'--enable-libxml' '--enable-session' '--with-mm' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' 
'--enable-xml' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-spl' '--enable-filter' 
'--disable-debug' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--disable-rpath' 
'--disable-static' '--enable-shared' '--program-suffix=5' '--with-pic' 
'--with-gnu-ld' '--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' 
'--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs2' '--disable-all' '--disable-cli'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you are running a machine with no (security) updates?! Even if it's not connected to the internet - who knows if that won't change at some point in the future!

Comment: Well, I know it won't connect to the internet, because it's only purpose is web task management for internal purposes.

Comment: It would still be a good idea to give it one-way access to the internet (no incoming connections from outside but outgoing connections) to keep it up to date!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll ask the infrastructure admin about the connection (since I would benefit from that also).

Comment: Tell him even internal machines need to be kept up to date since a potential attacker might be working at your company and thus have network access to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

type "configure --help" to find out anything you need then add to the configure command.

support for PDO with postGres you need **--with-pdo-pgsql=DIR** DIR is the PostgreSQL base
                            install directory or the path to pg_config

Comment: What I tried was running the config with the parameters from the phpinfo. It tells me that " apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs". Do I need that parameter?

Comment: I tried the config without apxs2 and it looks like he accepted it. What's the next step? What commands do I need to execute?

Comment: make && make install

Comment: Tried that, but make throws "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.". There are makefiles with extensions, guess it should only be "makefile". The reason he doesn't create it is probably because he throws this error in configure: "configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation."

Comment: Removed the libxml parameter, since I (think?) I don't need that. But now he's saying: "checking for PCRE headers location... configure: error: Could not find pcre.h in /usr"

Comment: download and install libxml from here.then --enable-libxml=DIR [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libxml2.html)http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libxml2.html

Answer (score 0):

I've talked to the admin. We have updated the machine with SP2, which also includes php 5.3.

I've got some configuration problems now, but I'll see if I can fix them, otherwise new question.

Thanks for the help anyway ;)